# Backbone.View does not show. But console.log see my object

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

It's my HTML

```
<script type="text/template" id="productTemplate">
            <p><%= title %></p>
                <h1><%= title %></h1>
                <img src="<%= img %>" alt="<%= title %>" />
                <p><%= text %></p>
            </script>
```

It's my JS code

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Product,
url: '/*there server url*/'
});
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName:'li',
className:'product-container',
initialize:function(){
this.render(); 
},
template:  _.template( $('#productTemplate').html() ),
render: function () {
    console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
   return this;
}
});
var Ajax =  new Products();
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName:'ul',
initialize:function(initialProduct){
    this.collection = Ajax;
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
    this.render();
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderProduct );
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
    },
render:function(){
    this.collection.each(function(item){
        this.renderProduct(item);     
        },this);
    },
renderProduct: function(item){
    var productView = new ProductView({
        model:item
        });
    this.$el.append(productView.render(item));
    }
});
$(function(){
var productsView = new ProductsView;
});
```

console.log(this.model.toJSON());
has view

> Object {id: 1, title: "product1", img: "img1.png", text: "lorem ipsum 1"}
>   Object {id: 1, title: "product1", img: "img1.png", text: "lorem ipsum
>   1"}

Comment: What is in your `$el` ? `console.dir(this.$el)`

Comment: @MysterX, there is no $el in the jQuery.fn.init[1]

Comment: @MysterX, in the jQuery.fn.init[1]:
0: li.product-container
length: 1
__proto__: jQuery[0]

Comment: You need to append your collection into DOM. Here's jsfiddle, a bit modified to simplify initialization (without server call).

http://jsfiddle.net/0gybnqoc/3/

Comment: Also note, that this.collection.fetch({reset: true}) is async, so collection may not be populated when you call render in initialize function. And you registered your listeners after collection.fetch, so it will probably will not call render on reset event.

Comment: @SciFiThief ok, let's i try

Comment: @SciFiThief thanks you, this is working!